# .USD files loads up with the wrong orientation in metal view

Tags: xcode, metal, usd

Any kind of .usd file doesn't get rendered the right way. In the model viewer, it's seen that the model's set up with the correct orientation. But when built, the orientation is completely off.

.obj files dont seem to have any such problem with orientation.

[Here's how it looks in the built app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LvjZO.jpg)
[Here's how it looks in the model viewer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DMmWX.jpg)

Tried importing the object into blender and manually changing the rotations but no dice
Also tried updating the rotation within Xcode itself but it doesnt allow me too, says the file cannot be autosaved (but that's a problem for another day)

Comment: This has nothing to do with Swift, Xcode or Metal. You are just using the wrong axis as up axis. USD supports both Y up and Z up. You need to make sure that whatever you are building and using can understand which axis is up in the model file and use the proper matrix.

Comment: You're right, I changed the up axis up to Y and it worked. Thanks!